# "Attempted to read or write protected memory" error when accessing COM component from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management, com-interop

I have an ASP.NET application which uses an old and now unsupported third party COM component. The Application runs reliably on windows server 2003, but when I try to run it on 2008 r2 or windows 7, I get the above message. Obviously i've switched the application pool into 32 bit mode.

I realise I will eventually need to replace this with a new component but for the moment I'm just trying to get this legacy app working in the new environment. I can change the C# code that calls it but I can't change the COM component itself.

any thoughts gratefully received

Andy

Comment: this link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809489/how-to-solve-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-error-with-progr

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure it's not DEP related as I have tried disabling DEP on the machine and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling your ASP.Net application targeting the x86 platform.

**Edit:**

Also when you recompile I would make sure to grab the new Interop it creates in relation to your COM component.

Comment: +1: Most of the time I've seen this is because the app is running in (or was compiled in) x64 mode